# Limit of sequence without using the exponential function

Tags: limits

How to calculate 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{n^{1000}}{2^n}\right)^n}$$ 
without using the exponential function?

Answer (score 1):

If
$f(n)
=(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{n^{1000}}{2^n})^n
$,

$\begin{array}\\
g(n)
&=\ln f(n)\\
&=n \ln(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{n^{1000}}{2^n})\\
&=n \ln(\frac{1}{3}(1 + \frac{3n^{1000}}{2^n}))\\
&=n(\ln(1/3)+ n\ln(1 + \frac{3n^{1000}}{2^n})\\
&=-n\ln(3)+ n\ln(1 + \frac{3n^{1000}}{2^n})\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\frac{3n^{1000}}{2^n}
\to 0
$
and
$\ln(1+x)
\sim x
$
for small $x$,
$n\ln(1 + \frac{3n^{1000}}{2^n})
\sim n \frac{3n^{1000}}{2^n}
\to 0
$
so
$g(n)
\sim -n\ln(3)
=\ln(3^{-n})
$
and
$f(n)
\sim 1/3^n
\to 0
$.

Used $\ln$, not $\exp$.